# asdf fails node install with: permission denied error, how to grant it permission?

Tags: linux, archlinux, asdf, asdf-vm

When I try to install a node version with asdf-vm, I get the following error message:

```
Trying to update node-build... ok
mkdir: cannot set permissions '/tmp': Permission denied
node-build: TMPDIR=/tmp is set to a non-accessible location
```

Comment: What have you tried? Run as sudo?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting TMPDIR to some directory that the installer can write to (it's running as you so anywhere you can write to should work).

For example: `export TMPDIR=~/tmp/`.

You may also want to report this issue to the maintainers of the asdf-nodejs plugin as the temp dir logic should work out of the box on all supported systems.